# How do I extract a movie from a DVD to put them on another CD?

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, encoding, ripping

I have some Movie DVDs, there are 3-4 movies in a DVD and I want to extract some particular movies from the DVDs to save them on another CD. Please let me know how can I do that.

I am using windows xp

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 8):

I have not encountered many commercial pressed Movie DVDs that have multiple titles, unless you're talking about ripping the extras, special features, etc.

[DVD Shrink](http://www.dvdshrink.org) will let you do that with reauthor mode, and rip only the main movie, and even combine title tracks together (such as Lord of the Rings two-disc special editions).

For legal reasons, you'll need to use a search engine to find a download link for DVD Shrink. Their site will tell you the latest stable version, though.

However, if you're not talking about a standard Movie DVD as purchased from a store, you'll need to clarify what format the discs are in that you're working with.

Answer (score 3):

http://lifehacker.com/380702/five-best-dvd-ripping-tools

There is some great rippers on lifehacker.com reviewed, and you can find various tutorials there too.

Comment: There's also lots of good stuff (including ripping guides) at www.doom9.org for the more technically inclined.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) on Mac OS X and Linux before with great success, and it appears they support Windows XP too.

You can download their software for free from [their website](http://handbrake.fr/).

Answer (score 0):

AnyDVD + Handbrake works well on windows. On Linux/Mac OS you just need Handbrake + VLC.